# Liquid theme customization based on selected locale

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I'm searching for locale customization on a shopify theme. I've looked here https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference but I'm not able to find any solution.

I need of something like this:

```
{% if page.selected.locale == "EN" %}
  add here customized them code for EN theme
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
{% if request.locale.iso_code == 'en' %}
  English content
{% endif %}
```